# setting jt400 server job library list, jobq and outq from a Job Description instead of the user profile

Tags: jt400

I have a web application that replaces a 5250 application.  I use jt400 for JDBC and other various IBM i services.
In the 5250 app, if a user had more than one role or business unit, A separate User Profile was created that referenced the appropriate Job Discription.

I'm implementing SSO for the Web Apps in the company.  So a user with multiple role/business unit responsibilities will only have one IBM i User Profile.

Since the IBM i prestarts jt400 server jobs ahead of need, and then swaps identities when an AS400 instance connects, I'd like the the library list, Job Queue and Output Queue set from a Job Description, not the User Profile

Can I do this once on the AS400 object instance?

I'd hate to have to manually do it for every server job which an AS400 instance connects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer, need to set the new OUTQ and LIBL after connecting byinvoking the CL commands on the new AS400 object